# Solving this operation with complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

Could someone tell me, which way of solving this problem
($|3 + 2i \cdot 4 + 3i|$) is correct?

First way:
$|3 + 2i \cdot 4 + 3i| = \\
|3 + 2i| \cdot |4 + 3i| = \\
\sqrt{3^{2} + 2^{2}} \cdot \sqrt{4^{2} + 3^{2}} = \\ 
\sqrt{13} \cdot \sqrt{25} = \\
\sqrt{13} \cdot 5 = \\
5\sqrt{13} \\
$

Or second way:
$|3 + 2i \cdot 4 + 3i| = \\
|3 + 8i + 3i| = |3 + 11i| = \\
\sqrt{3^{2} + 11^{2}} = \\
\sqrt{9 + 121} = \sqrt{130}
$

Please, help!

Comment: The notation is ambiguous so should not be used. Either interpretation might be what the author intended. I think the first is more likely. Parentheses would make that clear.

Comment: Multiplication is stronger than addition. Therefore, the first approach is wrong.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Never, of course. But the question is more interesting if it's the product of two complex numbers, since you can then take the product of the norms. And the numbers are nicer that way. So I suspect that's what was meant and there was a transcription error along the way - perhaps some student thinking the $+$ connecting the real and imaginary parts of a complex number somehow bound so tightly that the parentheses were unnecessary.